# Atomic write and tell for files in O_APPEND mode on linux

Tags: linux, system-calls, atomic

I am dealing with a situation where I want to save state persistently for an application that has many processes and many threads within those processes. Normally this would require a heavy use of locking to ensure
that there are no conflicts.

I wish to avoid this by saving the data into a file with the O_APPEND mode.  This way as long as I ensure that the data is <4KiB writes to the file will be atomic.  If I make use of append only data structures then I have a lock free solution.

However in order for this to work I need to know the location of the data within the file after I have written to that file. The problem that I am running into is that I am unable to find a system call that writes into
a file and then tells me the offset within that file that was written to.

I can use a write followed by a seek to discover this location.  However
this is not safe if another thread is sharing the same file descriptor so would require me to protect the write with a mutex which goes against my efforts to avoid locks.

Examining the man pages for write, writev, pwrite and prwritev has not shown anything that would carry out a write and then tell me the offset after the write as a single systems call and I'm fully aware that there may not be. Have I over looked something?

Comment: `writes to the file will be atomic` - how is this possible? You can block on I/O forever. `to save state persistently` - 1. Create another "saving" thread.  2. Have a `pipe()` shared between all threads. 3. Forward all the data from all your threads to this saving thread calling `writev` to the pipe. 4. The saving thread receives each message from each thread, does not need locking, can wait for I/O forever not blocking other threads. Another option, like some games currently do - suspend all threads (or not), fork your process, save the state in the child, continue the threads in the parent.

Comment: "writes to the file will be atomic - how is this possible?" The posix spec says that writes to files opened with O_APPEND are atomic for writes smaller then PIPE_BUF.  This doesn't work on nfs however but all the disk based fs support this.

Answer (score 0):

> If I make use of append only data structures then I have a lock free solution.

When code invokes `write` for a regular file, the first thing the kernel does is acquire the file read-write semaphore. All your writing threads serialize on that semaphore in the kernel.

See [`vfs_write`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.1.5/source/fs/read_write.c#L540), it calls `file_start_write` which eventually acquires the semaphore.

Comment: Well of course there are going to be kernel space locks and deeper down bus locks. I am trying to avoid user level locks that I have to manage.

Comment: @QthePlatypus [_lock free solution_ means a very specific and well-defined thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom): _if two threads can contend for the same mutex lock or spinlock, then the algorithm is not lock-free._  You misapply this term.